# Formula or VBA for week column creation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I think a picture is the easiest way to understand my problem, that is why I attached one. I have an identical production sequence of products (1-10) for each week. If I want week 4, I would copypaste another product range below week 3 and then manually add the "4" in the front. 
I know how to do the copypaste VBA, but I wouldnt know how to add the week in the front through VBA. Or is there a formula to accomplish this? This would be even better.

The main logic is: every time the production sequence (1-10) is repeated, the week count should increase by 1.

[image: Picture describing my problem]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Product 1 is in F3 then try this in E3 and fill down.

```
=countif(f$3:F3, F3)
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better (clearer) `=countif($F$3:F3, "Product 1")` ?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn No, because then you would only be counting the constant "Product 1" instead of exploiting the power of a relative reference.